# How can I connect multiple FPGA and send large data back and forth?

Tags: fpga

Let's say I have 4 identical FPGA boards running. They are doing some neural network calculation. All of them need to send/ receive data from each other back and forth and do their own calculations using that data. What is the best way/ IP/ protocol to  do data transfer between multiple FPGA boards? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is a simple question with a complex answer, RS232 at TTL levels between the boards is easy to implement, but if you have larger bandwidths you may need to take a look at parallel protocols. It also depends on your topology. Maybe just a big parallel bus with a clock and handshake signals.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please refer me to any tutorial or guideline from where I can start? Starting from scratch is almost impossible for me.

Comment: start thinking about the bandwidth you need, the distances, available voltages/tranceivers. Then you can get an idea of the requirements for the connections. With that either take a look at books you may have about protocols to choose what you want/need. As for impossible from scratch is that a time constraint or a limit inyour knowledge?

Comment: Parallel is not often the answer. Many FPGAs include high-speed serdes blocks, which can be used for a serial communication between multiple FPGAs on the same board.

Comment: Sure, but for a beginner serdes on top of all other things might be added difficulty. When enough gpios are available pins are not a limiting factor and using an oscilloscope to see what is going on also becomes easier. Sure maybe the project is too ambitious, but designing for your level of knowledge is, in my opinion, better then using the perfect technical solution that you don't understand. Start easy and get it to work, than expand. But you are right, serdes is another solution that will often give more bandwidth with fewer pins.